# iscroll issue when orientation change

Tags: jquery, iscroll, appmobi

I have an issue with [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) when I change the orienatation from portrait to landscape. It is working on AppMobi XDK, but on iPhone, it is not rendering properly. I have tried to trap the `orientationchange` event and called the refresh method of iScroll with different timeout values, but no luck.

```
// My code sample for the orientation change event
document.addEventListener("appMobi.device.orientation.change", orientationChange, false);
function orientationChange(){       
    setTimeout(function () { myScroll.refresh() }, 0);  
    //alert("Orientation Change");
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the event resize

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
// Get screen size (inner/outerWidth, inner/outerHeight)
}, false);
```